# How to install and run normal desktop applications on AWS machine( or any machine without a display)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

Let's say there is an application which generates/edit basic musical sounds and it doesn't have a API i.e. user can only use it via a GUI. I have a subscription of this application.

Now I want to install this application in my AWS  machine and automate some tasks on it.

Is there way to do this? What languages and tools will I need?

P. S. I am a web developer.

Comment: Are you talking about a super functional website with all the audio capacities of html5?  That requires html, JavaScript and some CSS. Heres the [Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Comment: Is this a theoretical example, so do you have something specific you are wanting to run? When you say "it has a UI for its users", is it a web interface, or a Windows application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly there's no such thing as to run that application through code only, you need a ui since you told us it has GUI, so how can we use the ui functions or the program without ui? if its through code and there is an api ready we might be able to code that and automate those stuffs.

But since theres a GUI for that, what i recommend is to launch a windows remote desktop server, install it there, and automate it using python automation tool, pygui.

Comment: So in an ubuntu based system on AWS-EC2, where we cannot see the GUI. If I have the application installed there. and I run pygui on it, would it still work?

Comment: No, as you have told, the app has an interface(GUI), so of course you do need a gui to make those automation with pygui.

but as i told if the app you are using have their api ready and available for devs to use, then i must say you can do it and automate those stuffs using the api they have provided.